# Reading multiple values from INI file using python

Tags: python-3.x, ini

I have a INI file from which I need to read multiple files:

```
[boy]
Gender=Male
Name=Jian
Age=23
```

When I do

```
def readINI(inp):
    configpath=path.relpath("roles.ini")
    config.read("roles.ini")
    if inp in config.sections():
            print(config.get(inp, 'Age'))
```

It gives me

```
boy 23.
```

But when I try to print multiple values like `print(config.get(inp, "Name" "Age"))`. It gives me error saying :

> **TypeError: get() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given**

Please help me out.